# attempting to destroy previous graph on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, chart.js

I am creating multiple graphs on the same canvas but I am unable to successfully use the destroy() API to clean up the previous data.

**HERE IS MY JS CODE FOR CREATING A CHART**

```
const getCountryDataByMonth = async (country) => {
document.getElementById('casesGraphHeader').innerHTML = "Loading....";
const response = await fetch ('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://pomber.github.io/covid19/timeseries.json');
const data = await response.json();

const reports = await data[country];
var i;
var dateList = [];
var caseByDay = [];
var deathsByDay = [];

for(i = 0; i < reports.length; i++){
  dateList.push(reports[i].date);
  caseByDay.push(reports[i].confirmed);
  deathsByDay.push(reports[i].deaths);
}
//GRAPH FOR TOTAL CASES
var casesOptions = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: dateList,
    datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Total Cases',
          data: caseByDay,
        backgroundColor: '#f49d12',
        borderColor: '#f49d12',
        fill: false,
        borderWidth: 2
        }
        ]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
         labels: {
             fontSize: 15
         }
     },
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
                    reverse: false,
          fontSize: 15
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          fontSize: 15
        }
      }],
    }
  }
}

var totalCasesChart = document.getElementById('totalCasesContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(totalCasesChart, casesOptions);
document.getElementById('casesGraphHeader').innerHTML = "Total Cases for "+country;


//GRAPH FOR TOTAL Deaths
var deathOptions = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: dateList,
    datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Total Deaths',
          data: deathsByDay,
        backgroundColor: '#e84c3d',
        borderColor: '#e84c3d',
        fill: false,
        borderWidth: 2
        }
        ]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
         labels: {
             fontSize: 15
         }
     },
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
                    reverse: false,
          fontSize: 15
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          fontSize: 15
        }
      }],
    }
  }
}


var totalCasesChart = document.getElementById('totalDeathsContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(totalDeathsContainer, deathOptions);
document.getElementById('deathsGraphHeader').innerHTML = "Total Deaths for "+country;

};

function renderChart(){
  getCountryDataByMonth(document.getElementById('myInput').value);
}


function defaultChart() {
    getCountryDataByMonth('US');
}
window.onload = defaultChart;
```

This is what I tried. I basically did

```
if(caseBar){
 caseBar.destroy();
}
```

However, this does not work. In my [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/x3tpjcf2/2/) you can try to type China first click to create the graph and then type Italy. Then HOVER over the Italy graph and you will see the stats from china appear on the graph.

Comment: Hard to answer (Your FIDDLE not working). Maybe run `update()` https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html. Example: https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/scriptable/bar.html

Comment: @EzraSiton Yeah it seems because api is saying too many requests but in my local machine it is working. How exactly would i integrate update as per my code? If(caseBar){caseBar.update()} ??

Comment: @EzraSiton my Fiddle is working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is riddle with issues, here is some of the stuff I see:

---

Look at what you are doing when you create the new charts:

```
var totalCasesChart = document.getElementById('totalCasesContainer').getContext('2d');
var caseBar = new Chart(totalCasesChart, casesOptions);
document.getElementById('casesGraphHeader').innerHTML = "Total Cases for " + country;
```

vs

```
 var totalCasesChart = document.getElementById('totalDeathsContainer').getContext('2d');
 new Chart(totalDeathsContainer, deathOptions);
 document.getElementById('deathsGraphHeader').innerHTML = "Total Deaths for " + country;
```

---

You are calling the:
`await fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://pomber.github.io/...');`
again and again when you should do it just once...

---

There are many variables that should be global to reduce what you do in `getCountryDataByMonth`, a perfect example are the `totalCasesChart` and `caseBar`

---

I made a few tweaks to your code here:
https://raw.githack.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/master/HTML/chart_test.html

Comment: how would i call it once? are you suggesting i store the json locally? the reason i call it everytime is because it gets updated... also can you help me with the destory issue?

Comment: @Dinero Here is the fix:
https://raw.githack.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/master/HTML/chart_test.html

Comment: Amazing you should post it as an answer so future readers may benefit or atleast add the link to the answer post.

Comment: @Dinero, yep, I edited the answer... but this is very specific to what you are doing I doubt many others will benefit ... something else you mentioned: I call it everytime is because it gets updated, how often does it get updated? we can add a setInterval to call the `getCountriesList` every 5 minutes maybe?

Comment: was looking at the source of the data: https://github.com/pomber/covid19/blob/master/readme.md `Updated three times a day` I don't think the setInterval to call the `getCountriesList` every 5 minutes is necessary if you want to see new data just manually refresh the page